# How to update foreign key of field from another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

i am trying to update field in another model by serializer.py but i get this error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sales_company_company_name_8f098bd8_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (company_name)=(fdsfasf) already exists.
```

serializer.py code:
Company model is a FK in Customer model

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = models.Company
    fields = ('company_name',)


class CustomersIsCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer
    company_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.company_name = models.Company.objects.update(company_name=validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name))
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.mobile = validated_data.get('mobile', instance.mobile)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.website = validated_data.get('website', instance.website)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = models.Customers
        fields = (
            'id',
            'company_name',
            'phone',
            'mobile',
            'email',
            'website',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'phone': {'validators': []},
            'mobile': {'validators': []},
            'email': {'validators': []},
            'website': {'validators': []},
        }
```

and my view code :

```
class CustomerIsCompanyGetIdPutPatchView(generics.RetrieveAPIView,
                                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = models.Customers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomersIsCompanySerializer

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        obj = generics.get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        return obj

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

but if i replace `update` and but `create` it work fine but it make a new line in the DB not update the old line.
for example if i replace that code :

```
instance.company_name = models.Company.objects.update(company_name=validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name))
```

by this code :

```
instance.company_name = models.Company.objects.create(company_name=validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name))
```

it work fine but not updated the old , it create new
just i want update the old in the company model

Comment: So, What's your problem/requirement ?

Comment: i want to update not to create i want it make new item in company table and give the customer the new id for this new company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for this problem this is what i want:

```
instance.company_name, created = models.Company.objects.get_or_create(company_name=validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name))
```

i used here **`created`** and **`get_or_create`** to see if it exist before made it directly `PUT` and edit The FK of the ***exist*** Company Name **OR** If it not exist create ***new*** one and `PUT` the FK of the new company name